# What is this widget called? "sliding pop-up"

Tags: jquery, html, widget, tumblr

sorry if I'm posting inappropriate subject.

I would like to ask about a certain widget found on
http://www.lyrics007.com/Calvin%20Harris%20Lyrics/I%20Need%20Your%20Love%20Lyrics.html

Whenever you scroll down a "Be sure to like this song!" pop-up slides out of the bottom. I would like to adapt that widget to my website too but I don't know how to do that. I tried to Google some terms "content slider, etc." but with no avail. Also I tried to inspect element but I didn't got very far with that either. Does anyone know how I would install this on my Tumblr blog?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called floating sidebar

Here's a jQuery tutorial on how to create floating side bar / menu :

[tutorials at netuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/creating-a-floating-html-menu-using-jquery-and-css/)

and a demo:

[Demo of floating div tutorials at netuts](https://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/018_Floating_Menu/demo/dhtml_float_menu_final_nettut.html)

you can expand the size of the div based on the user's interaction just similar to 
http://www.lyrics007.com/Calvin%20Harris%20Lyrics/I%20Need%20Your%20Love%20Lyrics.html

If you are not interested to build your own you can use this jquery plugin

[Floating side bar](http://designwoop.com/wp-content/uploads/stickysidebar/floating_sidebar.html)

Comment: Thank you! Definitely helpful!